# How to make R ignore duplicate entries in history?

Tags: r, configuration

R seems to remember all commands in history, including duplicates, which is really annoying. How can this behavior be changed?

For example, if I run these commands

```
    y = 3
    x = rnorm(15)
    x = rnorm(15)
```

I'll have to press up key three times to get to the first command.

Comment: What defines a duplicate? an identical call? or identicals in a row?

Comment: For example, run `x = rnorm(15)` twice.

Comment: @MatthewPlourde's question is whether `c; a; b; a` in your history should be stripped down to `c; b; a`. Your request is not unreasonable, but I think it's going to be very hard to do without deep hacking. A longer-term approach would be to start using a script-based workflow where you type your commands into an editor and then send them to R without changing focus (via hotkeys in RStudio/emacs/vim/Eclipse ...)

Comment: @CravingSpirit using `Rstudio`, you can search within history, once you get a command you can check it using: `the command in its original context`

Comment: You didn't state your OS.  The OSX R.app GUI has, IIRC, an option to do this to the history side-panel, at least.

Comment: @BenBolker I am on a linux machine, and I use ssh to connect to a server, which is also running linux, and start a screen session there. My editor is vim, so the vim-r-plugin is an option, except that it also uses screen for sending commands from the editor to the R console, implying a nested screen session, something that should perhaps be avoided.

Answer (score 3):

If you're filtering duplicates out regardless of order, the simplest thing to do is to add `pattern` argument to `history()`, e.g. `history(pattern="")`. Because of the peculiarities of `history` implementation, even having `pattern=""` will have the effect of filtering out the duplicates:

```
> history
...
    if (!missing(pattern)) 
        rawhist <- unique(grep(pattern, rawhist, value = TRUE, 
            ...))
...
```

And if you do care about the order, then just modify the stock `history` function, e.g.:

```
history_new = function(max.show = 25, reverse = FALSE, filter = FALSE, pattern, ...)
{
    file1 <- tempfile("Rrawhist")
    savehistory(file1)
    rawhist <- readLines(file1)
    unlink(file1)

    # the modification to stock
    if (filter)
      rawhist <- rawhist[cumsum(rle(rawhist)$lengths)]
    # end of modification

    if (!missing(pattern))
        rawhist <- unique(grep(pattern, rawhist, value = TRUE, 
            ...))
    nlines <- length(rawhist)
    if (nlines) {
        inds <- max(1, nlines - max.show):nlines
        if (reverse) 
            inds <- rev(inds)
    }
    else inds <- integer()
    file2 <- tempfile("hist")
    writeLines(rawhist[inds], file2)
    file.show(file2, title = "R History", delete.file = TRUE)
}
```

Comment: It looks like I have to used some dark hack to replace the history function in the utils package. http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Modify-base-R-functions-in-Rprofile-site-td905121.html  Are there better ways?

Comment: @CravingSpirit you can put it in your .Rprofile (and I guess call it `history` instead of `history_new`, maybe also set default value of `filter` to `TRUE` - whatever suits your needs best)

Comment: @eddi I have done as you suggested, but there seems to be no change. Anything else should be done?

Comment: check that your .Rprofile is indeed loaded - e.g. put any custom function in it and see that it works

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a duplicate command is a call identical to a previous one, regardless of order, you could simply do something like this:

```
tmp <- tempfile()
savehistory(tmp)
hist <- readLines(tmp)
hist[! duplicated(hist)]
```

or this, to preserve the last instance of a command

```
hist[! duplicated(hist, fromLast=TRUE)]
```

Comment: All good. If your concern that ";"-separated code were correct then one could also identify those lines and read them back in as text with sep=";".